# Recompiled APK not installing because it exists even though it's uninstalled

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, apktool

I have an android head unit for a car and the OS comes with an app pre-installed. And the developers often provide APK for the updates of the app. I took the latest apk and decompiled it with APK Toolkit and made some changes to some assets. I then recompiled it and when I go to install it, it does not install and throws and error saying the following:

> App not installed:
>
> The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name.

But I have uninstalled the app and it's just the recompiled apk that I cannot install. I am able to even install older versions of the original apk but just not the recompiled one. It's worth mentioning that some other apk's I can decompile and recompile without any issues and it lets me re-install it. But this particular app seems to have extra measures to prevent it.

I am thinking the original app's signature must be staying on the system as it's pre-installed and this is causing the issue.

Can anyone suggest possible solutions to overcome this issue? The device is not rooted and rooting unfortunately isn't an option.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you're uninstalling with some variant of `pm uninstall --user 0`? Perhaps that's why trying to reinstall the same package with a different signature fails, because it's still present in the system, as you've noticed. That being said, you might be able to avoid the issue if recompiling it with a different package name doesn't mess up the functionality of the app. That's one method a number of app cloning apps use.

Comment: If it is a pre-installed app, then it might be that you can't uninstall it. Instead you can only deactivate it and uninstall the latest updates.

Comment: @Shenk no i am just uninstalling it by going to settings and clearing cache and data then pressing uninstall. I'm not sure how you mean by pm uninstall --user 0. Can you kindly explain?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann not it 100% lets you uninstall it. The apps that you are not allowed to uninstall only has option to disable. But this one you can uninstall and they tell you to uninstall and update when they publish new apk with updates. And with their own apk's it updates all well. Just the recompiled one doesn't

Comment: @Ahmed If you are able to connect the device to a PC, you can [enable debugging](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#Enabling) and use [adb](https://developer.android.com/tools/adb) to run shell commands with slightly elevated permissions. The `adb shell pm uninstall --user 0` command is a trick to "uninstall" system apps without root permissions. Technically the app still exists in the system and can be reinstalled in a similar manner without needing to provide a download path. But it might be possible to even skip the "--user 0" flag entirely in this situation.

Comment: @Shenk thank you. Is there any other way to do it without having to connect via another device using adb? I need to see if I’m able to connect the device to adb as there is no usb on it as such.

Comment: Well many newer devices also have "Wireless debugging" availability. So if that's an option in the "Developer options" menu (available after tapping Build Number 7 times as described in the link above) then that could work. I don't know of any other straightfoward ways to do it. Also, to be clear I'm not guaranteeing that it'll work if you uninstall it this way, but it's worth a shot if you can make it work.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way to install a modified version of a pre.installed app that can not be fully installed. The `pm uninstall --user 0` does not fully uninstall an app if it is included in the system partition. In such a case you can try to modify the app so that it work with a different packageName (replace all occurrences where the app asks for it's own pavkageName and return the old name) or root the OS and modify the system partition to fully uninstall the app.